# Alexa Skill with Google OAuth

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-oauth

We are working on the Alexa Skill that uses the Google OAuth API for account linking. Everything works well on the Alexa skill.

Now, When we use the account linking using google account. On the OAuth consent screen when the Google API  Application type is selected to internal Shows the correct details i.e. Choose an account to continue to {Application Name}.  But When the Application type is selected to Public it shows the wrong details i.e. Choose an account to continue to {amazon.com}. Which is incorrect amazon.com isn't requesting for the information?

Our Google API Project isn't verified yet.

Any leads will be helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All public applications should apply for verification. If you are not using sensitive scopes, you should apply for brand verification for your app name to be displayed.

Read more about brand verification here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162#verification-types